# why jenkins source code management configuration none?

Tags: jenkins

While i am trying to configure my project on jenkins. i need to provide git. but in source code management option default none. how to add git.

[image]

kindly some one help me, thank you

Answer (score 8):

1. Read how to install a plugin: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugins#Plugins-Howtoinstallplugins
2. Install the git plugin: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me. 
Manage jenkins-> Manage plugins. 
Search for "Subversion" plugin. Select the "Subversion" plugin from the list and and click on install and restart Jenkins. 
Go to Job's configuration. Subversion should be listed under SCM (source code management.